# Does SF Automatically Assign the AccountId when using the <lightning:recordEditForm> for the Case object?

Tags: javascript, aura

I am using the lightning:recordEditForm on the Case object. Using the console and the JS Controller I can see that the Account Id that is selected by the user in the form is the Account Id that is being submitted. However it is not the Account Id that is on the Case at the end of the transaction. This is the code from the controller:

```
console.log('fields after'+JSON.stringify(fields));
cmp.find("recordForm").submit(fields);
```

There are no Processes, Workflow Rules or Flows affecting the AccountId after the submission. There are 2 managed Triggers for the Case object whose code is hidden.

Does Salesforce automatically assign the Account ID for the Case object when using the lightning:recordEditForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard Salesforce automation. Salesforce itself automatically assigns the AccountId based on the selected ContactId for the case. This happens in the Classic and Lightning UI, as well as API and Apex.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @DavidSwarbrick I think this may help: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335451&type=1